# How to assign value to mat-button?

Tags: angular, angular-material

```
<button type="submit" mat-button value="PC_Job005" (click)="clickCard($event)">View Details</button>
```

I'm trying to assign value to this button on angular. On click I can't find the value anywhere in the MouseEvent object. How could I give mat-button a value and then access it in an on click or (click)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can

```
<button mat-button (click)="clickCard('PC_Job005')">..</button>
clickCard(value:any)
{
   console.log(value)
}
```

//or

```
<button mat-button value="PC_Job005" (click)="clickCard($event)">..</button>
clickCard(event:any)
{
   //see that you need use currentTarget
   console.log(event.currentTarget.getAttribute('value'))
}
```

Comment: @sjjk001, the first method is only pass as argument to the function clickCard one string, not the target, (in most of cases pass the event in a click of a button is not necesary)